# How to order restaurants by votes for a certain date

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

I have restaurants with votes of users. Votes have the field date. I want to get restarants with votes for the certain date ordered by the count of votes. The query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r FROM Restaurant r " +
        "JOIN FETCH r.votes v " +
        "WHERE v.date=?1 " +
        "ORDER BY r.votes.size DESC
```

But it orders restaurants by the votes for all days:

```
order by
(select
    count(votes2_.RESTAURANT_ID) 
from
    votes votes2_ 
where
    restaurant0_.id=votes2_.RESTAURANT_ID) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like perhaps you should be aggregating by restaurant, something like this:

```
SELECT r.name, SUM(r.votes.size) AS cnt
FROM Restaurant r
JOIN FETCH r.votes v
WHERE v.date = ?1
GROUP BY r.name
ORDER BY SUM(r.votes.size) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to `ORDER BY` joined vote:

```
SELECT r FROM Restaurant r, v.size as cnt
JOIN FETCH r.votes v
WHERE v.date=?1
GROUP BY r.id
ORDER BY v.size DESC
```

Comment: The same result

Comment: what is the SQL?

Comment: order by
(select
    count(votes2_.RESTAURANT_ID) 
from
    votes votes2_ 
where
    restaurant0_.id=votes2_.RESTAURANT_ID) DESC

Comment: Hmm. If you use `v.size`, the votes table should be that used in the `JOIN`. And you say it's another one. Either there is a bug in HN or you run the old query. Can you change DESC to ASC, just to ensure the new query is used?

Comment: I delete desc and i have got restaurants sotred by votes for the all dates ascending

Comment: but the count of votes in the restaraunts corresponds to the date. But the ordering is wrong

Comment: And by the way, Tim is correct. You must group by a restaurant. Try this:
```SQL
SELECT r, v.size as cnt
FROM Restaurant r
JOIN r.votes v
WHERE v.date = ?1
GROUP BY r.id
ORDER BY v.size DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

The decision is:

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"votes"}) 
public List<Restaurant> findAllByVotes_date (Sort sort, LocalDate date);
```